# onOpen() function to open sheet in full screen modus

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, fullscreen

How can I open a Google Spreadsheet in full screen modus? I would like to use the

> onOpen()

function for that.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option with google script to open a google spreadsheet in Full Screen mode.

But I would suggest a pop-up displaying the shortcut to Compact control mode using google script.

So that when ever you open a spreadsheet a popup would show you the the shortcut for compact screen mode.

```
function onOpen() {
  Browser.msgBox('Press Ctrl+Shift+F to enter compact screen mode');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding this code to your Excel macro:

```
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

That should open it in full screen mode.

Comment: Based on the `onOpen()`, I can tell it has to do with Google Apps Script and thus Google Spreadsheet.